# DropDownListFor not selecting

Tags: html, asp.net-core

I have a `DropDownListFor` that doesn't seem to be setting the expected Model property. Here's the HTML:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedItem, 
        new SelectList(Model.ItemList, "Id", "Desc"), null, 
        new { @class = "selected-list", @size = "3" });  

    <div>
        @Model.SelectedItem
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Do Stuff" 
            asp-controller="My" 
            asp-action="DoStuff"
            asp-route-itemId="@Model.SelectedItem" />  
    </div>      
}
```

The `div` is just there for debugging purposes, and it either shows 0 or blank.
The underlying model has a property:

```
public int SelectedItem { get; set; }
```

I've also tried a string:

```
public string SelectedItem { get; set; } = String.Empty;
```

(Hence why 0 or blank)

The actual list itself displays fine, it just doesn't update the model on select. How can I get it to update the model?

Comment: "doesn't update the model on select"? What are you expecting? The value has to be posted to the server first before it will show in your div. It does not update automatically without any action on the client side.

Comment: I'm expecting to be able to access the selected value. From all the examples and docs I've seen, I thought this was the way to do that, but if it isn't then please let me know which the correct way is

Comment: The correct way is a broad term. It depends what you want to do? If you want the value client side you can use jquery to read the value of the ddl. But if you want it in your model you need to post it to the server.

Comment: @VDWWD You're right. I am, in fact, trying to post it to the server, however, I'm trying to leverage the asp-route property, which (based on your comment) may be the issue (question updated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `asp-route-itemId`, your action need contains parameter named `itemId` to receive the value. But for your scenario, it seems to be useless to receive such value, because it will always receive the value you set instead of the dropdown changed value.

Here is a simple demo you could follow and check if any difference with yours:

Model

```
public class TestVM
{
    public string SelectedItem { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public List<Item> ItemList { get; set; } 
}
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
}
```

View(Index.cshtml)

```
@model TestVM
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedItem, 
        new SelectList(Model.ItemList, "Id", "Desc"), null, 
        new { @class = "selected-list", @size = "3" });  

    <div>
        @Model.SelectedItem
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Do Stuff" 
            asp-controller="Home" 
            asp-action="DoStuff" />  
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    //Note: hard-coded the model just for easy testing.....
    var model = new TestVM()
    {
        SelectedItem = "1",
        ItemList = new List<Item>()
        {
            new Item(){Id=1,Desc="aa"},
            new Item(){Id=2,Desc="bb"},
            new Item(){Id=3,Desc="cc"}
        }
    };
   
    return View(model);
}
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult DoStuff(TestVM model)
{
    return View("index", model);
}
```

Result

[image]